# Is there a way to create a new P4 changelist using python subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess, perforce

This question from years ago does what I need:

[How do I check out a file from perforce in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184187/how-do-i-check-out-a-file-from-perforce-in-python)

but is there a way to do this using the subprocess module? (which I understand is the preferred way)

I've looked through stackoverflow, the python docs, as well as many google searches trying to find a way to use the stdin to send the required input to the p4 process, but I've not been successful. I've been able to find plenty on capturing the output of a subprocess command, but have not been able to grok the input commands.

I'm pretty new to python in general, so I am likely missing something obvious, but I don't know what I don't know in this case.

This is the code I've come up with so far:

```
descr = "this is a test description"
tempIn = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
tempOut = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
p = subprocess.Popen(["p4","change","-i"],stdout=tempOut, stdin=tempIn)
tempIn.write("change: New\n")
tempIn.write("description: " + descr)
tempIn.close()

(out, err) = p.communicate()
print out
```

Comment: I'd say that using the Perforce Python API, as the accepted answer for the question you linked to suggests, is the preferred way. (If there was no Perforce API and you were forced to launch the p4 process, then subprocess would be the way to do it.)

Comment: I've looked into the perforce API, however I'm trying to build a library of my own so I don't have to rely on a specific version of python, or wait for the API to get updated. I'm also using this as a way to functionally learn python, so the more I'm able to create on my own the more I'll understand how to use it in other situations.

Comment: I've also been forced to roll my own scripts simply because our company has some weird policies with external libraries. I would have to submit it for review and possibly wait months every time I want an update. Writing my own is sadly much less hassle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, [use the Perforce Python API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/184344/99377).

Regarding your code:

`tempfile.TemporaryFile()` isn't usually appropriate for creating a file and then passing the contents off to something else. [The temporary file is automatically deleted as soon as the file is closed.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile) Often you need to close the file for writing before you can re-open it for reading, creating a catch-22 situation. (You can get around this with `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)`, but that's still too round-about for this situation.)

To use `communicate()`, [you need to pass subprocess.PIPE](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate):

```
descr = "this is a test description"
changespec = "change: New\ndescription: " + descr

p = subprocess.Popen(["p4","change","-i"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

(out, err) = p.communicate(changespec)
print out
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank-you! I wasn't sure how the .communicate() worked, if there was formatting or such that needed to be adhered to. Thanks again!

Comment: I've been using this method in a few scripts for a few years now. It works just fine. I haven't run into any problems. This should certainly solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

if `stdout` is not unlimited then use [@Jon-Eric's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14287078/4279) otherwise replace `p.communicate()` with `rc = p.wait(); tempOut.seek(0); chunk = tempOut.read(chunk_size) ...`.