# Subprocess.Popen process.communicate() function error

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, perforce, changelist

I tried this [solution answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286418/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-new-p4-changelist-using-python-subprocess) to solve my problem but when using the solution I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "version_build.py", line 125, in <module>
    if __name__=='__main__': main()
  File "version_build.py", line 113, in main
    change = p4change(p4)
  File "version_build.py", line 90, in p4change
    change = p.communicate(changespec)[0]
  File "C:\Python36\Lib\subprocess.py", line 843, in communicate
    stdout, stderr = self._communicate(input, endtime, timeout)
  File "C:\Python36\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1086, in _communicate
    self._stdin_write(input)
  File "C:\Python36\Lib\subprocess.py", line 781, in _stdin_write
    self.stdin.write(input)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

**My main question is:** Why am I getting this error, am I missing something from the solution given to the other question?

I am using python3.
I have tried to use the str.encode() function, but when printing out the variable to the console, it is blank. `b''`

Here are the lines it is failing on (mainly the p.communicate line):

```
    changespec = 'change: new\n' + description
    
    p = subprocess.Popen([p4, 'change', '-i'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    change = p.communicate(changespec)[0]
    return change
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "p4 change" command is probably failing because you haven't provided it a valid changespec (or you aren't logged in, or any number of other possible errors).  To debug further you'll need to capture `stderr` from the command; there should be an error message that will explain exactly what's gone wrong.

See the comments in the answer you linked about using the P4Python API.  It's a much easier solution to this problem; among other things it will automatically surface errors as useful Python exceptions.